# intersection of infinite open sets

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

https://math.hws.edu/eck/metric-spaces/open-and-closed-sets.html

Please refer to Exercise 1.4 on the above link.

Consider the metric space $(\mathbb{R}, d)$. For $n=$1,2,3... let $\mathcal{O}_n$
be the open set $(1, 1+1/n)$

Show that {$\mathcal{O}_n | n=1,2,3...$}
is an infinite collection of open sets whose intersection is not open.

I think that the intersection of the above sets should be empty set, which is open set. So why is the intersection not open?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right (twice): the intersection is empty and the empty set is an open set.

The statement would be correct if $\mathcal O_n=\left(1-\frac1n,1+\frac1n\right)$, since then $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}\mathcal O_n=\{1\}$.